# How to securely set authorization header using angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, authorization, angularjs-http

It is common to authenticate to web services using an authorization header which contains a secret token. And since the security of this mechanism depends on the token to be *secret* care should be taken that this token is not leaked.

There are countless tutorials on the web which explains how such an authorization header can be set using angular and least the ones that I have actually read use an $http interceptor and now one discusses that the token is not leaked.

There are some public and some private APIs out there which can be talked to cross domain thanks to CORS. And obviously I do not want to send my internal authorization tokens on any of those requests.

Some other techniques come to mind such as setting the token manually only on each and every request, but that means lots of duplicate code. The $http server could be wrapped in an $authenticatedHttp service so that it is always appearent from the object used whether it is the authenticated service or the normal one. However the $http service has so many methods to be wrapped.

Is there a better solution?

**UPDATE**

From the answers I have the impression that my question was not understood. I try it with a more concrete example:

I have a private web page. People have to login with username/password and let's say for simplicity's sake that we use HTTP basic auth, so username/password are bas64 encoded and are transmitted on every request in the HTTP header "Authorization". So far there is no problem.

But there is this great&free weather widget. I can retrieve the current weather information in JSON format from https://myWhateverWeatherService.tld/weather.json. After the login to my private web service I also retrieve the weather information (CORS allows me to do this).

The problem is that even though myWhateverWeatherService.tld does not require any authentication at all, angular's $http service will still append the Authorization header. And I don't trust the guys at myWhateverWeatherService.tld. Maybe they just set up the service so they can steal Authorization token and do lot's of nasty stuff with them.

I need some reliable way to deal with that. I already thought about checking the url with some regex in the interceptor. This is possible, but it is also not to difficult to forget about a certain case that my regex will miss.

Answer (score 0):

The token is always sent through the wire, I guess that is the most vulnerable part of it.

Since the token must always be present on the http header itself, the only way to make the request more secure is to encrypt the whole request, and for that you should use SSL.

If you are concerned about the safety of storing the token on the client machine, you can keep it only on the browser´s memory, without persisting it on a localstorage or something like that. So every time the user closes the browser and open it again, s/he must log in.

Comment: The answer to "sending over the wire" is SSL, that's easy. I think you misunderstood my quesion. The request header does not always need to be present. It should not be present on requests to some third party server which is not under my control.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I totally missed that part. In that case, the only way to avoid sending your token to third parties is to separate those calls. If they are fewer than your own calls, I recommend you build a wrapper that removes the header with the basic methods instead of checking every single request. So, to shorten things up, use $http with interceptor for your own trusted endpoints and a wrapper with no auth header for the rest.